# is it possible to access a specific string in a file

Tags: c, arrays

I've read a file called names.txt which contains firstname and secondname. I printed the names out, just to see, if it's working

```
for (int counter = 0; counter < 10; counter ++) {
  fscanf(names, "%s %s\n", firstname, secondname);
  printf("%s%s\n", firstname, secondname);
}
```

I tried to access a specific string with firstname[x] but this gets me the single char in the firstname

is it possible now, to only print let's say the 7th firstname and secondname of the red file names.txt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (int counter = 0; counter < 10; counter ++) 
{
    fscanf(names, "%s %s\n", firstname, secondname);
    if(counter==6)
    printf("%s%s\n", firstname, secondname);
}
```

This code will now print only 7th firstname and secondname,

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you just want to print the 7th name, put a condition around your `printf`:

```
if (counter == 6)
    printf("%s%s\n", firstname, secondname);
```

Now just some general comments on other problems with your approach.  Firstly, you are doing no bounds checking on your inputs, which can potentially cause a buffer overflow.

The general recommendation for reading strings from the file is using `fgets`.  That reads an entire line, provided your buffer is large enough.  You can then split that line into names using `strtok` or simply finding the first space with `strchr`.

Another issue is you're not testing whether the input succeeds.  `fscanf` returns the number of elements successfully read.  If that is not equal to 2, you should probably abandon your loop.

Last of all, you're looping exactly 10 times, which makes a somewhat bold assumption as to the contents of the file.  Perhaps you want to exit the loop after reading the 7th string.  Who knows?  But either do that, or loop until reading a line fails.